# Azure SQL exports fail to backup in blob container

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a database in Azure SQL database, single database. It is Northwind sample that I have created in Azure SQL database, by using scripts. I am trying to export this database into blob storage in a storage account Gen 2. I have created a storage account in the same resource group where my Azure SQL database, single database resides. Via the portal I export the database. In firewall settings of my database, I have already checked "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" as shown below:

[image]

I have also added my IP address to have access.

When I click on export I can see my storage account, and the container to save my backups (export database files) as shown below:

[image]

However, when I click OK and my export request is submitted, after a few minutes, I can see in "Import/Export History" that my request status remians on "Running, Progress=1%" and later the status changes to "Failed".

[image]

When I check my blob container in the storage account I can see the files are there all with 4B size as show below:

[image]

What is the cause of this and how can I resolve it? Basically I want to export the database into a blob storage by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export#:%7E:text=The%20Azure%20portal%201%20To%20export%20a%20database,Settings%20and%20then%20click%20Import%2FExport%20history.%20See%20More.) but it is failing to export. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Azure SQL Server's Import/Export history should have details about the failure.  BACKPAC export can fail for an annoyingly-large number of reasons.

Comment: The error it is raising is: "The Azure SQL Server firewall did not allow the operation to connect. To resolve this, please select the "Allow All Azure" checkbox in the Sql Server's configuration blade." But I have already allowed it. The first screen shot above showed it is set to yes.

Comment: Dunno.  You can run the export from anywhere with the SqlPackage utility. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15 or SSMS under Database/Tasks/Export Data-tier Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to export the database bacpac file in blob storage account.

Follow the below steps:

1. Open the SSMS in your local machine and login to your Azure SQL Server. Fill  the required details and click on **Connect** as shown below.

[image]

2. Right click on database you want to backup. Follow **Task -> Export Data-tier Application**.

[image]

3. Select **Save to Microsoft Azure** option. Click on **Connect** to connect with your Azure account and provide storage account details. Click on **Next**.

[image]

4. On the next page, check the summary of your settings and simply click on **Finish** button.

Once finished, you can check the bacpac file in your storage account. See the image below for your reference.

[image]

**Additional step may required:** If the authentication was cached, you need to run `DBCC FLUSHAUTHCACHE;` command in Management Studio and it will exported perfectly.

Comment: Thank you @Utkarshpal-MT. Basically I had exactly followed the same procedure you mentioned. However, still exports were failing. At the end I understood, authentication was cached. To resolve the issue I ran this command in Management studio: DBCC FLUSHAUTHCACHE; After that the exports worked perfectly well.

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks for sharing your findings. I'll add the details in my answer to help other community members.